# Invariance Scaling of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic

Prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\log\left(\int_0^t \exp(B_s)\mathrm{d}s\right)$ converges to $\sup\limits_{t\in [0,1]}B_t$ in distribution as $t\to\infty$. I have a sense to use scaling invariance, but no idea how to derive this whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t e^{B_s}ds &= t\int_0^1 e^{B_{tu}}du\\
&=t\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}B_{tu}}du\\
&=t\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{t}W_u}du,
\end{align*}
where $\{W_u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}B_{tu}, \, u\ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \ln \int_0^t e^{B_s}ds &= \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{t}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\ln \int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{t}W_u}du\\
&= \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{t}} + \ln \bigg(\int_0^1 \left(e^{W_u}\right)^{\sqrt{t}}du \bigg)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}\\
&= \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{t}} + \ln\, \big\lVert{e^{W_u}}\big\rVert_{\sqrt{t}}\\
&\rightarrow\ln\, \big\lVert{e^{W_u}}\big\rVert_{\infty}\\
&= \ln\Big( \max_{0\le u \le 1} e^{W_u}\Big)\\
&=\max_{0\le u \le 1} W_u.
\end{align*}
That is, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \ln \int_0^t e^{B_s}ds$ converges to $\max_{0\le t \le 1} B_t$ in distribution, as $t\rightarrow \infty$.